# Mysql query select * and also include case when

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I was wondering if there is a way to have a mysql query like below:

```
SELECT * , CASE WHEN p.price IS NULL THEN pp.price ELSE p.price
FROM table names
WHERE ....
```

I know how to use the 'CASE WHEN ELSE' but I am not sure if it is possible to include it in a query that retrieves all fields.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Normally you would use:  `COALESCE(p.price, pp.price)`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but you should include its object.

select names.*,CASE WHEN p.price IS NULL THEN pp.price ELSE p.price end
FROM table names
WHERE ....

Note: Tables of p and pp objects should be joined with table (names)